# How to extend existing entity in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have read the documentation on [Extending Non-Abstract Entities](https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Extending-Existing-Entities#extending-non-abstract-entities), and done that accordingly (inherit the `Edition` entity). But the `Up` function in migration class is empty.

`MyEdition` class is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Abp.Application.Editions;

namespace Boilerplate.Editions
{
    public class MyEdition: Edition
    {
        public virtual long Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The migration is automatically generated using Add-Migration command of Entity Framework Core.

My migration is below:

```
public partial class Added_MyEdition_Entity : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

So, how to extend existing entity in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Comment: Try to set the Up method to public

Comment: "But the Up function in migration class is null", what? Methods cannot "be null"

Comment: @andreasnico The method is automatically generated

Comment: Auto generated migration functions body is empty default. You write alter, add, delete scripts/code with your requirements. If your configuration is `AutoMigration = true` one migration `InitialMigration` files is enough. If you want to manane your source, you have to write `up` and `down` body.

Comment: Just because your class inherits from a persistable entity does not mean that EF will persist it to the DB. You have to add it to a DbSet and configure it in the ModelBuilder (`ModelBuilder.Entity<MyEdition>().ToTable(nameof(MyEdition))`). Then EF will recognize that it has to scaffold a `CreateTable` statement in the migration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBContext has no idea of this new class so you have to add the below line in you DBContext class.

```
public virtual DbSet<MyEdition> MyEdition { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did it!